# Two tensorflow tensors of shape T1 = N*D, T2 = M*D; M < N. T1 has rows in T2. Find indices of rows in T1 tensor for each row in T2

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two Tensors T1 (N * D dimension) and T2(M * D dimension)(M is less than N). T2 rows are guaranteed to be in T1. For each row in T2, Is there a way to find the indices of T1 where the row matches?
I am able to solve the problem using eager execution.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
tf.enable_eager_execution()
x = tf.random_normal([15,3])
y = x[:2] # first two entries 
y= tf.concat([y,x[8:9]], 0)
output = []
for row in x:
   if row.numpy() in y.numpy():
     output.append(True)
   else:
     output.append(False)
```

Could someone provide help for executing without eager execution?
How do we perform the same operation if T1 and T2 are batches? i.e. T1 - B * N * D and T2 - B * M * D

P.S. How do we search for a row in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do that:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def find_row_indices(t1, t2):
    # Compare every pair of rows
    eq = tf.equal(tf.expand_dims(t1, -3), tf.expand_dims(t2, -2))
    # Find where all the elements in two rows match
    matches = tf.reduce_all(eq, axis=-1)
    # Find indices where match occurs
    idx = tf.argmax(tf.cast(matches, tf.uint8), axis=-1)
    # Find where there has been no match
    has_match = tf.reduce_any(matches, axis=-1)
    # Return match index of -1 if no match found
    return tf.where(has_match, idx, -tf.ones_like(idx))

# Test
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    tf.set_random_seed(100)
    x = tf.random_normal([15, 3])
    y = x[:2]
    y = tf.concat([y, x[8:9]], 0)
    idx = find_row_indices(x, y)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        print(sess.run(idx))
        # [0 1 8]
```

It has quadratic space and memory cost, because it compares every pair of rows to each other, so having two very big inputs could be problematic in some cases. Also, if there is more than one matching index, this method does not guarantee which one of them will be returned.

EDIT: The function above can also be used with arrays with more initial dimensions. For example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    tf.set_random_seed(100)
    x = tf.random_normal([4, 15, 3])
    y = tf.gather_nd(x, [[[ 0,  3], [ 0,  6], [ 0,  2]],
                         [[ 1, 10], [ 1,  5], [ 1, 12]],
                         [[ 2,  8], [ 2,  1], [ 2,  0]],
                         [[ 3,  9], [ 3, 14], [ 3,  4]]])
    idx = find_row_indices(x, y)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        print(sess.run(idx))
        # [[ 3  6  2]
        #  [10  5 12]
        #  [ 8  1  0]
        #  [ 9 14  4]]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How can we do the same operation if T1 and T2 has batches? i.e. T1 - B * N * D and T2 - B*M*D?

Comment: That's a bit different to the original question... There are two possible interpretations for that, you can do it per example in the batch (so you get a `B x N` tensor as output) or for the whole batch as a single block (so you get a `N` tensor as output).

Comment: @user3048926 I have edited the function so it works in the initial case but also with a batch dimension, in the first sense that I mention in me previous comment (which I assume is what you meant...).